# Unity Xiaomy android phone dont save progress

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, xiaomi

My game (unity) works fine on my phone and others, but i have one device with Mi firmware on it and i have troubles with saving game progress.

I don't know why but save not works after closing the app.

Does somebody have the same problem?

Thanks,
Dmitriy

Comment: Any code about you are saving the progress?

Comment: Just the common PlayerPrefs.SetInt, SetString

Comment: Post the code even if it's just one line of code. Just post the code that shows how you are saving the scene.

Comment: I found error in my code, sorry!